# How to fix 'TypeError: join() ' When displaying DB Images in Django Templates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display some images uploaded to my DB via the admin page using the image.url attribute. When the page loads, the image.url is correct, but the terminal shows an internal server error with the traceback ending with 
"TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'"

I can't find where specifically the join method is called as the traceback seems to only talk about internal files.

I thought it might be related to an override save function, but commenting the function out yields the same results.

settings.py STATIC and MEDIA and MEDIA_URL are all set.

Template:

```
 <img class='project-details-image' src="{{ project.image.url }}
```

Model:

```
image=models.ImageField(upload_to='project-covers/', default='/Default.png', null=True)
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/my_portfolio/my_portfolio/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_portfolio/static'),
]
MEDIA_ROOT = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_portfolio/img'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/img/'
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/user/django-portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/django-portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/django-portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/django-portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 36, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "/home/user/django-portfolio/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 32, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

Id like to be able to use the template tag feature to show the related image from the database. Currently I am only trying to display my default image, however, the actual image will be one folder lower.

Comment: can you add your BASE_DIR ? I mean declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#media-root) should be a `string` not a `list`.

Change:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_portfolio/img'),
]
```

To:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_portfolio/img')
```

Comment: Good catch.  I completely missed that.

Comment: Haha. Thank you!

Comment: Oh my goodness, you have no idea how long I have been stuck on this error. It's so frustrating that it was such a simple fix but I have to admit I probably never would have caught that! thank you so much! everything seems to be working now!